# Change one image from html to many different images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i was able to change img src using javascript, however, I can't figure out how to add multiple images to one function so that when I click on the image it should keep on changing images, it only works with one image
please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">all abount sports</h1>
    <img id="cool" src="intro-1647872367.jpg"  onclick="changeImage();">
</body>
</html>

<script>
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('cool');
  if (image.src.match("beverages-carbonated-drink-cold-drink-1571849")) {
    image.src = "intro-1647872367.jpg";
  } else {
    image.src = "beverages-carbonated-drink-cold-drink-1571849.jpg";


  }
  
  
}

</script>
```

Comment: Try using eventListener, with click - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Declare an array of images, and a counter variable. On click, increment the counter and use that image. Make sure to wrap the counter back to 0 when you're at the last image.